# Is Mobile Web URL enough to add an app domain in Facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

When I first tried to add an app domain to my Facebook app, it gave the following error..

> Error You have specified an App Domains but have not specified a Site
>   URL or a Mobile Web URL  must be derived from your Site URL
>   or your Mobile Web URL.

OK.  So i added a Mobile Web URL.  Now I am able to add an App Domain.  I click save.
But When i come back to the page **App Domain field is empty**

But if I fill in the Site URL field under "Website with Facebook Login",  I am able to give the app domain and the app domain field stays put.

**SO BASICALLY, to give an app domain, I must give a SITE URL, even if I am not using "Website with Facebook Login"**   Is that Correct?